# Google Drive API PHP resumable

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am using dropzone js with chunking to take a large file and break it up, each one of those pieces are getting sent to PHP and all the pieces of that large file have a mime type application/octet-stream (if you put the chunk files together it will be video/mp4) now what I am trying to do is put the file back together in Google Drive and here is my PHP code:

```
public function addFile($filename, $content, $description = '')
    {
        $file = new \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
        $file->setName($filename);
        $file->setParents([$_ENV['FOLDER_ID']]);
        $file->setDescription($description);

        $result = $this->driveService->files->create(
            $file,
            [
                'data' => $content,
                'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
                'uploadType' => 'resumable'
            ]
        );

        return sprintf('https://drive.google.com/file/d/%s/view?usp=sharing', $result->getId());
    }
```

The problem I am having is each chunk is getting uploaded to my Google Drive when I am expecting 1 file put together, is what I am trying to do even possible?

Comment: PHP does not know about chunked uploads, it just sees a bunch of separate file uploads. You need a handler server-side as @andrew suggests. Alternatively, many cloud storage providers can give a signed URL for uploading directly from the client, though you'd likely need to use a completely different client-side library for the upload.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would have to write the chunks to the server's local disk into one file. You can use `file_put_contents( $filename, $chunk, FILE_APPEND );`

then use, the dropzone `complete` event handler to notify the server via async request that the upload is complete

```js
myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
  myDropzone.removeFile(file);
  fetch('/upload-complete', {method:'POST', file})
});
```

```php
//upload-conplete.php
$file = $_POST['file'];
// chack status of uploaded file here
var_dump($file);
// add file to Google drive here if all is well
```

Comment: So what you are saying is I would have to put my file back together and send it to the Google Drive API?

Comment: correct, yes you need to accumulate the chunks on the server into a single file, then send the resultant file to Google drive

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the media uploader from the [large-file-upload sample](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/examples/large-file-upload.php)

```
$file = new Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
$file->name = "Big File";
$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

// Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
$client->setDefer(true);
$request = $service->files->create($file);

// Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
$media = new Google\Http\MediaFileUpload(
    $client,
    $request,
    'text/plain',
    null,
    true,
    $chunkSizeBytes
);
$media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));

// Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
// complete.
$status = false;
$handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    // read until you get $chunkSizeBytes from TESTFILE
    // fread will never return more than 8192 bytes if the stream is read
    // buffered and it does not represent a plain file
    // An example of a read buffered file is when reading from a URL
    $chunk = readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

// The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
// that has been uploaded.
$result = false;
if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
}

fclose($handle);
```